# Strange behaviour on string::size() in C++ when multiplied by a negative integer

Tags: c++, stdstring

Running this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string a = "Hello, world!";
    cout << (-1)*a.size() << endl;
}
```

I get:

```
18446744073709551603
```

which is clearly not what I want. This annoying bug happens every time I try to multiply a string::size() by a negative number (but not for positive!). I can't figure out what is the problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `(-1)*a.size()`, `(-1)` has type `int` and `a.size()` has an unsigned type (probably `size_t`).

`(-1)*a.size()` is computed as an unsigned integer, because promotion and conversion rules favor unsigned types when binary operations are applied to a signed type and an unsigned type.

Comment: @Joe, it's not always as simple as that, especially for types smaller than `int`.

Comment: @Joe I am not a specialist of C++, but in C it is a little more complicated than that (and probably C++ has the same rules). if `long` can represent all the values of `unsigned int`, then the operation between a `long` and an `unsigned int` will be done as a `long` operation.

Answer (score 0):

size() returns an unsigned integer. Try explicitly casting size()'s result to a signed int or float before multiplying... that should do it.

Comment: @Neel Basu: Casting to float can be helpful in at least one instance: when the unsigned value ofthe size_t is too large to fit into a signed integer variable. Not sure that's a concern here, though.

Answer (score 0):

size is unsigned. if you want negative size you have to cast it:

```
cout << (-1)*(int)a.size() << endl;
```

or on 64 bit:

```
cout << (-1)*(long)a.size() << endl;
```

beware that for sizes above `2,147,483,647` (`9,223,372,036,854,775,807` for 64 bit) will produce wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string::size()` returns `size_t` which is unsigned so cannot handle negetive numbers. thats why when you multiply it with `-1` you get this kind of answer

Comment: The return type of std::string::size() is std::string::size_type - not (std::)size_t.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/ mentions it as `size_t` which is defined in `<cstddef>`

Comment: According 21.3.3 of the C++03 standard the return type of std::basic_string<..>::size() is std::basic_string<..>::size_type.

Comment: @Simon: I Believe for `std::string`, that `std::basic_string<..>::size_type` is a typedef of `size_t`.

Comment: @NeelBasu: Don't quote `cplusplus.com`, they hide typedefs and have other inacruacies.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `size()` is of type `basic_string::size_type`, which is unsigned. The [Integral Promotions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc9te331.aspx) dictate that: *"If int cannot represent the full range of values, then the object is promoted to type unsigned int."*

So, the type of `(-1)*a.size()` is unsigned, which than then gets printed by `std::cout` accordingly.

To get "what you want", simply cast that value to a signed integer, but be careful the use the integer type that is large enough regardless of platform "bitness", for example:

```
cout << static_cast<ptrdiff_t>((-1)*a.size()) << endl;
```